# Angular + NET Core "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"

Tags: angular, http, cors, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to send a GET request from my angular app to my .NET Core WebAPI backend. Both are running on localhost. Angular is running on port 4200, WebAPI is running on port 5001. When I make the GET request in Angular, the following error is shown in console:

[image: Console error]

After searching online, almost every answer comes down to an issue with CORS not being enabled correctly on the backend server. However, to my knowledge, I have CORS setup correctly. Here is my configuration for CORS:

[image]

[image]

This is the service function in Angular as well as the GET method in WebAPI:

[image]

[image]

I know the URL is correct, because, when I copy the URL into Postman, it works as intended.

Mainly I'm wondering if I did mess up CORS, because that seems to be the main issue with this error message, or if there is something else I may have missed.

**EDIT (Solution)**:
Ok, so through various trials and errors, I believe I have found the issue. When I made the initial project, I made the project in JetBrains Rider. I decided to try making a new project in Visual Studio to see what would happen, however, the problem still remained. As it turns out the issue was not with CORS, but with an invalid HTTPS localhost certificate. When I tried to run the console command `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` I did not get a popup to confirm the certificate, but instead just a generic error message that was not useful. Here is how I fixed the issue (whether or not this is the right way can be for discussion).

1. Ran the WebAPI and opened the site in Chrome.
2. On HTTPS connections, Chrome will allow you to see the certificate info by clicking the "Secure" or "Not Secure" tag next to the URL. I clicked that and opened the certificate info window.
3. There is a tab called "Details" where I was able to save the certificate to my computer.
4. Once the certificate was saved, I could right-click it and there was a right-click option called "Install Certificate".
5. I installed the certificate just clicking next and leaving the values as default. After that the Angular app now makes GET, POST, PUT, etc requests as expected, and when I copy the Web API URLs into Chrome, Chrome now says the connection is secure rather than not secure as it was doing before.

Comment: try using chrome cors extension. If the get request works when the extension is enabled, that means the problem is definitely with CORS configuration in your backend.

Comment: I've had issues with IE and Chrome where it wont let you make the call if the security certificate is bad.  Try just jamming the rest call into the url bar of the browser and make sure you don't have to accept a cert for the host.

Comment: @yer So I installed the Chrome extension and enabled it, however, the error is still there.

Comment: use http :// localhost:5001 instead of https, do you have https configured on local backend server ?

Comment: yes, as @nitin mentioned use http instead of https

Comment: @nitin All http requests get automatically redirected to https (the way the project got setup automatically). Should web api requests not be made with https? I could remake the project in visual studio and disable the https configuration option, but in a real world scenario you want https.

Comment: I seemed to have fixed the issue. I updated my post to show what I did.

Comment: You should use .environment file to manage local & production builds. This way it will be easy to user http on local and https on production builds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so through various trials and errors, I believe I have found the issue. When I made the initial project, I made the project in JetBrains Rider. I decided to try making a new project in Visual Studio to see what would happen, however, the problem still remained. As it turns out the issue was not with CORS, but with an invalid HTTPS localhost certificate. When I tried to run the console command `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` I did not get a popup to confirm the certificate, but instead just a generic error message that was not useful. Here is how I fixed the issue (whether or not this is the right way can be for discussion).

1. Ran the WebAPI and opened the site in Chrome.
2. On HTTPS connections, Chrome will allow you to see the certificate info by clicking the "Secure" or "Not Secure" tag next to the URL. I clicked that and opened the certificate info window.
3. There is a tab called "Details" where I was able to save the certificate to my computer.
4. Once the certificate was saved, I could right-click it and there was a right-click option called "Install Certificate".
5. I installed the certificate just clicking next and leaving the values as default. After that the Angular app now makes GET, POST, PUT, etc requests as expected, and when I copy the Web API URLs into Chrome, Chrome now says the connection is secure rather than not secure as it was doing before.

This is the error I was getting when running `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` for reference:

[image]

Comment: I'm getting this error on production and UAT, any idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem but it was not related to the certificate.

Simply, just omit HTTPS redirection from the configure method on `startup.cs` did the trick for me.

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

Then, you should set your Angular application to send the requests to the `HTTP` protocol instead. The default should be: `http://localhost:5000`.

Alternatively, you can wrap the HTTPS redirection in `isProduction` check in order to not forget to bring it back for the deployment.

```
if(env.IsProduction()) {
  app.UseHttpsRedirection();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your Angular app is sending requests to the wrong port.

> Consult your environment.ts and or environment.prod.ts files within your angular project (if this is where you've defined your backend URLs).

> Make sure the URL and port match those of the .NET app.

> Alternatively, you can change the URL from your backend/.NET core app to match those found in your angular project.

Happy coding!